# How to make a dynamic component in interface layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to develop a calculator app.

The app is already complete and can be run successfully, but the problem is my app just only utilize half of the screen. I want my app to use all of available space.

**XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSatu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDua"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="2" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTiga"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="3" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBagi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=":" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEmpat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLima"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="5" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEnam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="6" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKali"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="x" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTujuh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="7" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelapan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="8" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSembilan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="9" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTambah"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="+" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSamadengan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="=" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="C" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKurang"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="-" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` (or `match_parent`, as `fill_parent` is deprecated) in the first `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you want your outermost `Layout` to fill the screen, you should use `match_parent` for both `layout_width` and `layout_height`. Then, to get the inner `View`s to fill it, you need to use `layout_weight`s. When using weight, the dimension you want to auto-size should be set to `0dp`, and only one can be set as such for any given `View`. Given that, adjusting weights between the `LinearLayout`s and the `Button`s, you can get the layout you want.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"/>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnSatu"/>

        <Button android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnDua"/>

        <Button android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnTiga"/>

        <Button android:text=":"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnBagi"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnEmpat"/>

        <Button android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnLima"/>

        <Button android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnEnam"/>

        <Button android:text="x"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnKali"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnTujuh"/>

        <Button android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnDelapan"/>

        <Button android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnSembilan"/>

        <Button android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnTambah"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnNol"/>

        <Button android:text="="
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnSamadengan"/>

        <Button android:text="C"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"/>

        <Button android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnKurang"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```